# Can $(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times (-\infty,x]$ be seen as a product space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Consider the following set: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2||y\leq x\}$.

It could be informally written as: $\mathbb R\times (-\infty,x]$

Can it be seen as a product space?

It seems really wierd and I think the answer is "no".

--

Edited according to comments.

I acknowledge that the notation is very very informal. It is adapted from the notation in:

$$\int_{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times\mathbb R}f(x,y)d(x,y)$$

$$\int_{(x,y)\in\mathbb R\times (-\infty,x]}f(x,y)d(x,y)$$

Comment: It can't be informally be written as you say, because you are possibly the only person in the world who reads $\Bbb R\times [0,x]$ like that.

Comment: I think $ℝ × [0..x]$ is not just informal, but extremely sloppy. Also I think you mean something like $ℝ×(-∞..x]$.

Comment: That being said, $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, y\le x\}$ is, for instance, homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\times [0,\infty)$ via the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: "Seen as a product space" - what do you mean by that? If you mean as a topological space, then yes, and @Gae.S. comment shows that. Another way of looking at that is that it is simply a (closed) half-plane "below" the line $y=x$, i.e. by rotating it (by $-45^\circ$) it "becomes" the half-plane $y\le 0$ i.e. $\mathbb R\times(-\infty, 0]$ in a yet another way.

Answer (score 4):

If $\{(x,y): y \leq x\}=A \times B$ then, for any real number $a$ the point $(a,a-1)$ belongs to the left side hence to the right side. It follows that $a \in A$. Similarly every real number is in $B$. [Consider $(a,a+1)$ for this]. Thus $A=B=\mathbb R$ and $\{(x,y): y \leq x\}\neq A \times B$